# Three Integers into 1 string with spacebars;

Tags: c++, string, int

I have input like this:

```
1581 303 1127 Bravo
```

I want to put it into strings like this:

```
string a="1581 303 1127";
string b="Bravo";
```

How can i do that?

Comment: Are you saving 1581, 303, 1127 in int or just taking as string?

Comment: What have you tried so far? How did that work? How didn't that work? Where is the input coming from?

Comment: First 3 are ints, last one is string

Comment: The "spacebar" is not a character, it is the key that you press to write a space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the fact that you take first three as int and last as string do it like this.

`int i1, i2, i3;
//Take input in three integers
sprintf(a, "%d %d %d", i1, i2, i3);`

Comment: You can use sprintf for the string b but use %s this time

Comment: You can't use `sprintf` with the C++ standard library class [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).

Comment: After that std::string s(charArry);

Comment: This is a C approach.   Yes, it can be used in C++, but is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

Just read them as strings and put them together.

```
std::string x1, x2, x3;
std::cin >> x1 >> x2 >> x3;
std::string a = x1 + " " + x2 + " " + x3;
std::string b;
std::cin >> b;
```

Answer (score 1):

a simpel c++ style approach would be using `std::to_string`

```
string += " "
string += std::to_string(int_value);
```

this adds an " int" value at the end of your string.

But have you consider using string streams instead?

```
#include <sstream>

std::stringstream sstream;
sstream << int_1 << " " << int_2 << std::endl;
```

and if you wish convert it to an good old string:

```
string = sstream.str();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
getline(cin, a); // read the numbers followed by a space after each number and press enter 

getline(cin, b); // read the string 

cout << a << endl << b; // output the string with numbers

// first then the string with the word 'Bravo'
```

Answer (score 0):

A way in standard C++ that doesn't rely on reading the values is

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    int i1 = 1581;
    int i2 = 303;
    int i3 = 1127;

    std::ostringstream ostr;
    ostr << i1 << ' ' << i2 << ' ' << i3 << ' ' << "Bravo";

     // possible to stream anything we want to the string stream

    std::string our_string = ostr.str();    // get our string

    std::cout << our_string << '\n';     // print it out

}
```