# Convert array of uint8_t to string in C++

Tags: c++, ostringstream, uint8t

I have an array of type uint8_t. I want to create a string that concatenates each element of the array. Here is my attempt using an ostringstream, but the string seems to be empty afterward.

```
std::string key = "";
std::ostringstream convert;
for (int a = 0; a < key_size_; a++) {                                               
  convert << key_arr[a]
  key.append(convert.str());
}

cout << key << endl;
```

Comment: How do you want your `uint8_t` to be converted: as numbers or as characters? E.g., should 65 become "65" or "A"?

Comment: I think this link will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29298204/three-integers-into-1-string-with-spacebars/29298421#29298421

Comment: `key` seems to be your data source and data destination. Could you fix your code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
std::ostringstream convert;
for (int a = 0; a < key_size_; a++) {
    convert << (int)key[a];
}

std::string key_string = convert.str();

std::cout << key_string << std::endl;
```

The `ostringstream` class is like a string builder. You can append values to it, and when you're done you can call it's `.str()` method to get a `std::string` that contains everything you put into it.

You need to cast the `uint8_t` values to `int` before you add them to the `ostringstream` because if you don't it will treat them as chars. On the other hand, if they do represent chars, you need to remove the `(int)` cast to see the actual characters.

---

EDIT: If your array contains 0x1F 0x1F 0x1F and you want your string to be 1F1F1F, you can use [`std::uppercase`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/uppercase/) and [`std::hex`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/hex/) manipulators, like this:

```
std::ostringstream convert;
for (int a = 0; a < key_size_; a++) {
    convert << std::uppercase << std::hex << (int)key[a];
}
```

If you want to go back to decimal and lowercase, you need to use [`std::nouppercase`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/nouppercase/) and [`std::dec`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/dec/).

Comment: Without the cast, the string is still empty. With the cast, it works. If the key array contains 0x1F, 0x1F, 0x1F, 0x1F, and 0x1F, then I would want the string to be 1F1F1F1F1F.

Comment: In order to print values as uppercase hex, you can use `std::uppercase` and `std::hex` manipulators. I edited my answer to add this info.

Comment: Case isn't too important. But the std::hex and int casting was perfect. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

Probably the easiest way is

```
uint8_t arr[];
// ...
std::string str = reinterpret_cast<char *>(arr);
```

or C-style:

```
std::string str = (char *) arr;
```